# Active Directory Authentication & MS SQL Server in ArcReader

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcreader

I'm having difficulty with a single user (That I know of) being able to access geodatabase files in our ArcGIS Server using ArcReader.

Our setup is as follows: Enterprise Geodatabase within MS SQL Server 2012, Active Directory integration within SQL Server (GIS Edit group & GIS View group), mixed environment of ArcGIS users and viewers.

Every other GIS user with either ArcReader or ArcView can access the geodatabase data, but this new user I have added to the ArcView group cannot see the layers. The PMF map shows all of them as unavailable. Her ArcReader has the server connection in the proper folder to allow for OS authentication, and I even tried putting her in the edit group but she still cannot access the layers.

We're running 10.2 server and she has 10.2.1 ArcReader.

Comment: related http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9916-Can-t-access-SDE-Geodatabase-feature-class-in-ArcReader-10 see http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39370

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I did this, as well, with no noticeable change. It should be noted that this was for 10.0 not 10.1 or 10.2, which are entirely different products. And I'm also using SQL Server 2012 not 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my own mistake after a few days of headache. Mapperz had the right fix and it still is necessary for 10.2, however, if you are using Sql Server 2012 you need the 2012 native client. I had mistakenly installed the 2008 client and it did not work obviously.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Link to the 2012 native client, though you have to scroll down quite a ways to find the individual file you need.